# Alert Success or Error message for jQuery POST method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following jQuery to submit and save data:

```
var data = "Sample data";
$.post('@Url.Content("~/Student/SaveData")', { Data : data}
//I want to alert SUCCESS or ERROR here
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(string data)
{
  try
  {
      //Add logic to save data
      //pass SUCCESS indication.
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      //pass ERROR indication
  }
return View();
}
```

I want to alert success message if data saved successfully otherwise error message. How to handle it in jQuery section?

Answer (score 1):

you are firstly using wrong helper instead of `@Url.Content` you need to use `@Url.Action` which generates url for you action:

and use `$.ajax` like this:

```
 var data = "Sample data";

$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveData","Student")',
                type: "get",
                data: { sample:data}
                success: function (res) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");

                }
            });
```

and your action would be like:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(string sample="")
{

return Content(sample);

}
```